# Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined Apollo query

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I use Apollo Client to work with GraphQL API and When I try to send query request first time using **client.query()** I get the error like in the screenshot,[image: with enabled Debug JS Remotely] [image: without enabled Debug JS Remotely] but request works and after I click dismiss button If I send request again I don't get this error. I get this error only when I send request first time and only QUERY request, mutation works fine. Any idea Why it happens?

**QUERY request**

```
export const oauthRedirectURLRequest = (params: IOAuthRedirectURLParams) => {
client.query({
    variables: params.variables,
    query: OAUTHREDIRECTURL
})
.then((result) => store.dispatch(oauth_redirect_url_success(result.data.OauthRedirectUrl)))
.catch((error) => store.dispatch(oauth_redirect_url_failed(error.graphQLErrors)))
}
```

**Apollo Client**

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: API_URL,
});

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const user_token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user-token');
  const guest_token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('guest-token');

  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  const params = {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: user_token ? user_token : guest_token
    }
  };

  return params;
});

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the error as text rather than image. That would make it an immaculate question.

Comment: The problem was due to an error in the apollo-link-dedup package and solution to solve this problem was downgrade the version of apollo-link-dedup package to 1.0.0